# Facebook iOS SDK installation via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, cocoapods

I'm trying to update Facebook-iOS-SDK pod to latest 3.18.0 version but after running command

> pod update

I get many error messages:

> Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.18.0)
>   [!] /usr/bin/git submodule update --init --depth 1
>
> Submodule 'Bolts-IOS' (git://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS.git) registered for path 'Bolts-IOS'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/OCHamcrest' (git://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest) registered for path 'vendor/OCHamcrest'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/OCMock' (git://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock) registered for path 'vendor/OCMock'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/OHHTTPStubs' (git://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs.git) registered for path 'vendor/OHHTTPStubs'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/appledoc' (git://github.com/tomaz/appledoc.git) registered for path 'vendor/appledoc'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/ios-snapshot-test-case' (git://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case.git) registered for path 'vendor/ios-snapshot-test-case'
>
> Submodule 'vendor/xctool' (git://github.com/facebook/xctool.git) registered for path 'vendor/xctool'
>   Cloning into 'Bolts-IOS'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: d679df70933da29463e44e15f4ce4f740d7b5dfd
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/OCHamcrest'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: da09243ef136883fa8cea7ea2d42f48a9256fbdf
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/OCMock'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: 2191c124a93f535056e5cae05d55545a415fcde1
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/OHHTTPStubs'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: c87ded1ac299bc659a7e36bac43cac094bf7adb9
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/appledoc'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: d2e65f8c2faa066acfea2dbb51a5ec2d5364c7ec
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/ios-snapshot-test-case'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: a04ea585a5efb6cce6e5cd17f568eb1e6c472b2c
>
> Cloning into 'vendor/xctool'...
>
> fatal: reference is not a tree: f8720fe7e6af818054328c0325c7e9ce195f7c7c
>
> Unable to checkout 'd679df70933da29463e44e15f4ce4f740d7b5dfd' in submodule path 'Bolts-IOS'
>
> Unable to checkout 'da09243ef136883fa8cea7ea2d42f48a9256fbdf' in submodule path 'vendor/OCHamcrest'
>
> Unable to checkout '2191c124a93f535056e5cae05d55545a415fcde1' in submodule path 'vendor/OCMock'
>
> Unable to checkout 'c87ded1ac299bc659a7e36bac43cac094bf7adb9' in submodule path 'vendor/OHHTTPStubs'
>
> Unable to checkout 'd2e65f8c2faa066acfea2dbb51a5ec2d5364c7ec' in submodule path 'vendor/appledoc'
>
> Unable to checkout 'a04ea585a5efb6cce6e5cd17f568eb1e6c472b2c' in submodule path 'vendor/ios-snapshot-test-case'
>
> Unable to checkout 'f8720fe7e6af818054328c0325c7e9ce195f7c7c' in submodule path 'vendor/xctool'

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I got same error and meanwhile I use older version `pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.17.0'`

Comment: @DanielBauke, I use older version too but hoped somebody knows the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error with facebook sdk 3.18.2, but when i updated pod to 0.34.1 it's solved.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043597/how-to-install-facebook-sdk-for-ios-using-cocoapods), `Facebook-iOS-SDK` has been deprecated (see the message cocoapods give you when you use `pod install`) You should use:

```
pod "FBSDKCoreKit";
pod "FBSDKLoginKit";
pod "FBSDKShareKit";
pod "FBSDKMessengerShareKit";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but seems that you didn't notice that this question is quite old and was asked before FBSDKCoreKit, etc release.

Answer (score 0):

Delete pods, .symlinks, pubspec.lock. Next do:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

This served me