# How to install facebook sdk for iOS using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

In the facebook's documentation:
Here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

It's written that we could use:

```
pod \'Facebook-iOS-SDK\'
```

For installing pods in our project. But I added it in the pod file at line 10 and try to run pod install, it shows following error on terminal:

```
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

It appears to have originated from your Podfile at line 10.

Search for existing github issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%2FUsers%2Fprajeetshrestha%2FDesktop%2FHotRents%2FPodfile%3A10%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%24undefined%0A++++pod+%5C%27%2FUsers%2Fprajeetshrestha%2FDeskt...%0A+++++++++%5E%0A%2FUsers%2Fprajeetshrestha%2FDesktop%2FHotRents%2FPodfile%3A13%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+tCONSTANT%2C+expecting+keyword_end%0Atarget+%27HotRentsTests%27+do%0A+++++++++++++++++++++%5E%0A%2FUsers%2Fprajeetshrestha%2FDesktop%2FHotRents%2FPodfile%3A13%3A+unterminated+string+meets+end+of+file%0A%2FUsers%2Fprajeetshrestha%2FDesktop%2FHotRents%2FPodfile%3A13%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+end-of-input%2C+expecting+keyword_end&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
```

Comment: Changing the pod link to 
pod "Facebook-iOS-SDK". Solved it why do they put \' in documentation? What's it for ?

Comment: You should delete this comment and instead post it as the answer to your own question and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`Facebook-iOS-SDK` has been deprecated (see the message cocoapods give you when you use `pod install`).

According to [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) You should use:

```
pod "FBSDKCoreKit";
pod "FBSDKLoginKit";
pod "FBSDKShareKit";
pod "FBSDKMessengerShareKit";
```

Comment: Yes it has changed from when i have asked. This is the correct answer now.

Comment: nice - couldn't find the messenger pod anywhere..thanks

Comment: and how to import the pod library written in objective c headers in swift?

Comment: Got it. import FBSDKMessengerShareKit import FBSDKCoreKit import FBSDKLoginKit import FBSDKShareKit

Comment: here is the link from facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate

Comment: why fb not mention this pod in FB developer documentation ?

Comment: is this still the correct way? this answer has been here a long while..

Answer (score 2):

Changing the pod link to

```
pod "Facebook-iOS-SDK"
```

solved it why do they put \' in documentation is the question now?

**EDIT**: This answer is now **outdated**. The correct way to install facebook Pod is as @aramusss described above.

Comment: Guessing it’s a mistake. Might want to see if you can report a bug.

Comment: This has been superceded by FBSDKCoreKit

Comment: [!] Facebook-iOS-SDK has been deprecated in favor of FBSDKCoreKit