# Getting react-native-fbsdk to work with CocoaPods

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I've been trying to get `react-native-fbsdk` to work with CocoaPods, since I much prefer fetching the Facebook SDK as part of the `pod install` process, but I haven't had much luck. I'm aware that I can `react-native link` the npm library and manually download and add the necessary frameworks, but this seems rather silly when I have a perfectly good package manager at my disposal.

Judging by [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced) it should be fairly straight forward - just add the necessary pods to the `Podfile`, right? But no matter what I try the native FBSDK modules never seem to be included. I've tried a whole host of different `Podfile`s, some with `use_framework!` and `pod 'Bolts'`, some with just `pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'`. This is the one I'm currently on:

```
target 'FacebookPods' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

  target 'FacebookPodsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

But when I run my test app and try to do anything with the `react-native-fbsdk` module I get errors complaining about various native modules being undefined. Here's my `index.ios.js` file, trying to access the `LoginManager`:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import {AppRegistry, Text} from "react-native"
import {LoginManager} from "react-native-fbsdk"

export default class FacebookPods extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"])
      .then(() => console.log("Success!"))
      .catch((err) => console.log("Failure!", err))
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>Hello World</Text>
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("FacebookPods", () => FacebookPods)
```

But this throws the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions'` in `FBLoginManager.js`. Further inspection of NativeModules shows that no native FBSDK modules are included at all. I also get the following warnings at launch:

```
2017-07-13 19:50:19.006 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLikeView" does not exist
2017-07-13 19:50:19.007 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist
2017-07-13 19:50:19.008 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSendButton" does not exist
2017-07-13 19:50:19.009 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTFBShareButton" does not exist
```

So yea, I'm at a complete loss. In my mind, simply adding the pods ought to be enough to include the frameworks. I've scoured the interwebs for any additional steps that I might've missed, but there isn't much, save for a few issues on the `react-native-fbsdk` project that have since then been removed.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about pods but do you need to provide a path? `pod 'FacebookPods', :path => 'path/to/lib/'` From my memory, Facebook had me install the SDK in `~/Documents` so it may be an issue with downloading/finding the lib

Comment: Maybe, I believe the `FBSDK*Kit` pods are also specified in the `react-native-fbsdk` package, which would be fine. But the whole idea is to avoid downloading and installing the SDK outside of the project and manually dragging in the frameworks. Did you get it to work using CocoaPods?

Comment: No, we just did the manual install.  This question talks about installing the normal FBSDK with pods https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847447/3473220 Not sure how RN complicates it though

Comment: react-native-fbsdk includes native sources, if you import those with cocoapods the react-native module won't have the proper header search path thus cannot find the appropriate modules and that is why you have an error.

Comment: It can be tricky if your native project is in swift since facebook doesn't give a damn and don't test anything with swift projects, so you can expect the documentation to be 90% non accurate when it comes to swift

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this issue and managed to get `react-native-fbsdk` working with the Facebook SDK installed by adding the following to my pod file:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

and importing the following in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Note that these imports are different from the suggestion in the `react-native-fbsdk` readme. That's because `FBSDKCorekit.framework`, `FBSDKShareKit.framework` and `FBSDKLoginKit.framework` are not available.

You also need to link `libFBSDKShareKit.a`, `libFBSDKCoreKit.a` and `libFBSDKLoginKit.a` from the `General` tab in Xcode. These are the only three Core/Login/Share things available to link. They refer to the pods, and looking in the pods directory you see there are no `.framework` files, just `.h` files, so those are the ones we import into AppDelegate.m. That (I think) gives `react-native-fbsdk` all the files in the the SDK components that it needs.

Comment: I don't see any of those libFBSDKXXXXKit.a to be added, only one is added and that's libRTCFBSDK.a. Is that fine? I'm using FBSDK 5.3.0

Answer (score 6):

It's working for me with my Podfile set up this way (not sure Bolts framework pod is needed):

`pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'`

And I had to do `react-native link` to make sure that the `libRCTFBSDK.a` is in the xcode's Build TARGET => build phrases => "Link Binary with libraries" list.  If not, you probably need to add the `libRCTFBSDK.a` in manually.  I found that once I ran the `react-native link` and the `libRCTFBSDK.a` is in that list, xCode then compiled correctly.

Comment: I think `react-native-link` should be `react-native link`

Comment: I'm having this issue and I can see that there's no libRCTFBSDK.a in the link binary with libraries step. When I try to add it, I'm unable to see it in the list either. How do I get this file?

Answer (score 0):

If you use cocoapods, react native will use cocoapods to link link libraries. I created a new project then install and link all packages before run 'pod init' and 'pod install'. Maybe this error from cocoapods when link packages. All packages need 'react-native link' you installed after run 'pod install' it not working. I think we can deintegate cocoapod before run react native link.